# Angular swPush.requestSubscription is not returning anything on First Call

Tags: angular, push-notification, service-worker, angular-service-worker, react-native-push-notification

I am using `swPush` in my angular project. In that, the event of `this.swPush.requestSubscription()` is getting called by clicking a button.

For Example:

this `getdeviceToken` will call

```
getDeviceToken(): Promise<any> {
        console.log('getting device token')
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                if (this.swPush.isEnabled) {
                    console.log('before subscription')
                    let sub = await this.swPush.requestSubscription({
                        serverPublicKey: this.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY
                    })
                    console.log('temp --------', sub)
                    if(sub) {
                        this.device_token = sub;
                        if(sub) {
                            console.log('if sub')
                            resolve(this.device_token);
                        }else{
                            console.log('else sub')
                            reject({ message: "Error getting device id"});
                        }
                    } else{
                        reject({ message: "Error getting device id"});
                    }
                } else{
                    console.log('sw is not enabled');
                    reject({ message: "Error getting device id"});
                }
    }
```

After hard reload, when I click the button for the first time it is getting stuck on the
`console.log('before subscription')`

and returns nothing. It makes my app unusable since the function not returning anything not even an error. So I cannot move forward.

But when I do a simple reload and click the button again it works and `this.swPush.requestSubscription()` returns me a promise so my app is moving forward. Anyone know Why it is not working for the first time ? Or any suggestions to improve this.

Comment: this is happening to me too. Cleaning cache and hard reloading worked but after sometime it too stopped working

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution working, IDK how but it worked everytime...

1. Set push-notification permission to Ask(default) in the page
2. Ask for permission from user using `Notification.requestPermission().then( result => { getSubscriptionData(); });`
3. avoid using chrome as it checks for security, data coming from any server except https:// are blocked. Use updated EDGE or firefox instead

please comment out any other solution if you have... here's my full code:

```
constructor(private _floatNotifications: FloatNotificationService,
    private readonly _swPush: SwPush,
    private _apiService: APIservice) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSubscription();
  }

  getSubscription() {
    console.log(Notification.permission);
    if(Notification.permission === 'default') {
      Notification.requestPermission().then(() => {
        this.requestSubscription();
      }).catch(() => {
        // show permission denied error
      });
    }
    else if(Notification.permission === 'denied') {
      // show permission is denied, please allow it error
    } else {
      this.requestSubscription();
    }
  }

  async requestSubscription() {
    try {
      const sub = await this._swPush.requestSubscription({ serverPublicKey: ServiceKeysEnum.PUSH_SUBSCRIPTION_PUBLIC_KEY });
      console.log("subscription object ", sub);
    } catch  (e) {
      this._floatNotifications.makeToast.next({header: "Task failed", text: "failed to get subscription object"+e, DurationsEnum: DurationsEnum.MEDIUM, type: "danger"});
    }
  }
```